# Manage Model Permissions Dynamically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a the models:

1. File
2. FileGroups
3. User
4. UserGroups

I'd like to be able to manage the user's permissions to file's based on whether or not they are in a certain group. Now these permissions aren't set in stone and can be altered by an administrator through the UI.

Are there any rails specific gems that can help out with this? I believe declarative auth isn't something that would suit my needs as it is explicitly defined in the code.

Any insight would help. Anything to save me from coding a permissions system myself.

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used:

1) cancan - https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

and

2) acl9 - https://github.com/be9/acl9